# This condition will always return true when I try to check string value in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a *phone* variable, which is of type number. I need to check if the first two digits are not equal to 33 or 32, so I converted it to string, then stored the first and second digits to perform the comparison.

```
  let phoneText = this.phone.toString();
  let digit1 = phoneText.charAt(0);
  let digit2 = phoneText.charAt(1);
  let twoDigits: string = digit1+digit2;
  if ( (twoDigits!= "33") || (twoDigits!= "32") ){
    alert("Invalid");
  }
```

However, I got this error message regarding the if statement, and I don't understand what the problem is.

```
This condition will always return 'true' since the types '"33"' and '"32"' have no overlap.ts(2367)
let start: "33"
```

Comment: your condition will always return true because even 33 or 32 yields true for this statement, let alone 17. you want to negate the entire thing and use && instead of ||

Comment: If `twoDigits` is `"32"` then it's not `"33"`. If `twoDigits` is `"33"` then it's not `"32"`.

Comment: You want `(twoDigits != "33") && (twoDigits != "32")`. Alternatively (De Morgan's): `!((twoDigits == "33") || (twoDigits == "32"))`.

Comment: Also, consider using [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead of `charAt()` twice then concatenation: `let twoDigits: string = phoneText.substring(0, 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number is 32:
First condition is `true`. You get `true`.

If number is 0 or any other number:
First condition is `true`. You get `true`.

If number is 33:
First condition is `false`. Second condition is `true`. You get `true`.

This is the scenario for which the error exists. Only in this case will the second condition will ever be evaluated. Now at that point you are basically comparing 33 with 32, two values which are different. TS realizes this and gives you the `no overlap` error.

It is like [doing this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHhC8FgE4FcQG4CwAoAlgMwAoBZAQzAAsA6REgOwBMB7AWwIEoIA+CABkoFYIAHyHQ48PCWABnEGwDe2CBADGjWtMahKwRgHMCAInI5DbTFgC+QA)

```
let x = true;
if(Math.random() > 0.5 || x == false){
  console.log("hi");
}
```

What you want is  :

```
  let phoneText = this.phone.toString();
  let digit1 = phoneText.charAt(0);
  let digit2 = phoneText.charAt(1);
  let twoDigits: string = digit1+digit2;
  if ( (twoDigits!= "33") && (twoDigits!= "32") ){
    alert("Invalid");
  }
```